# Manipulating lists in R

Tags: r

I have a list that looks like this:

```
mylist <- list("a", "b", "c", NA, "d", "e", "f", NA, "g", "h", "i", NA, "j", "k", "l", NA,
               "m", "n", "o", NA, "p", "q", "r", NA, "s", "t", "u", NA, "v", "w", "x", NA,
               "y", "z")
str(mylist)
# List of 34
# $ : chr "a"
# $ : chr "b"
# $ : chr "c"
# $ : logi NA
# $ : chr "d"
# $ : chr "e"
# $ : chr "f"
# $ : logi NA
# $ : chr "g"
[list output truncated]
```

I want it to look like this:

```
str(mylist)
$ : chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
$ : chr [1:3] "d" "e" "f"
$ : chr [1:3] "g" "h" "i"
[list output truncated]
```

In other words, I want a list in which all of the elements up to each NA is made into its own list. I suspect this is not difficult to do, but I can't figure it out!
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try:

```
lapply(split(unlist(x), cumsum(is.na(x))), function(z) z[!is.na(z)])
```

Comment: To avoid having to call `is.na` so often, one could do `u = c(NA_character, unlist(x)); lapply( split(u, cumsum(is.na(u))), tail, -1)` or something.